# Animation Nodes Loop Input performance issue with large 3d vectors numpy arrays

Tags: python, animation, node-editor, performance, numpy

I am working on scientific visualizations involving huge arrays of 3d vectors, sometimes 100k or sometimes even millions of vectors. I quickly ran into performance related issues, mostly when needing to iterate over arrays of vectors, or even values, using Loop Inputs.
Case in point, the attached blend file, that "spiralizes" a linear segment. I generate an 1D array of numpy values between a and b using:

interpolated_values = np.linspace(value_a,value_b,number_of_elements)

and I invoke that in a 3d vector combine node in x and rotate every vector in the array around it's Z-axis using a multiplied value of it's own index. In order to do that I have to iterate over the array using a Loop Input node. So far so good, it works, but the performance is a killer. Already by 1k iterations the scene lags like crazy on a quite powerful machine. Comparatively, if I do exactly the same in XSI's ICE, I can generate over 100k vectors before the scene starts lagging.
Is there a better way to achieve this than using Loop Input, which is the culprit here? Using a for loop in Python doesn't work of course, as the for loop is first executed in the script and then called in AN...
Here is the attached blend file https://we.tl/t-L8snsm1VOE

Comment: I am not sure how familiar you are with AN and autoexecution? Do you know what autoexecution does? If not, you should think about using triggers...https://docs.animation-nodes.com/documentation/introduction/execution/

Comment: Thank you for your answer Chris, but that doesn't really solve the lag, it just delays it until the code gets executed. I mean, it doesn't bring anything to improve the performance, if I have to wait 20 minutes for the code to iterate over a 100k by any change of value or some kind of other trigger.

Comment: well...this wan't an answer - it was a comment ;)

Comment: thank you for your comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is executing the script node every iteration so I added a float list parameter to the loop and put your script node outside of the loop. On my machine instead of about 350ms execution time I got about 50ms execution time with it outside. about 7 times improvement.
[image]

Comment: Something like this I had in my mind - but radoo „knew“ better ;) well done!

Comment: Hi Richard, thank you! That's awesome!

Comment: Jesus, Chris, :D How is your comment about autoexec and triggers having anything to do with Richard's solution?

Comment: Hi radoo, would you be able to mark the question as answered, please? Also there is a you tube channel called "Thinking Penguin" who does stuff on animation nodes. He has a video called "Speed Up Performance in Animation Nodes by Caching" which I think you will find useful for your sort projects with large arrays.

Comment: Hi Richard, I know that YT channel, as well as the caching mechanism. Right now I am trying to speed things up with Numba + Cuda for large arrays. Another idea would be to maybe port most of the code externally and let it run in a parallel instance + IO on a Ramdisk idk yet

Answer (score 1):

Animation nodes have `fromNumpyArray()` function which can be used to convert numpy arrays without much overhead. For example a 1d array can be converted to float list by `DoubleList.fromNumpyArray(myArray.astype('float64'))`.

Here you can see conversion speed for 1million numbers:
[image]